# Parse rendered MVC url to controller name , action name and parameters name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking a solution how to parse a link in mvc into controller name, action name, parameters name.

Ex: `http://mydomain.com/company/view.aspx?display=1&type=myCompany&id=1.` I'm using IIS version 6.0

It will parse like 
**controller name**: company
**action name**:view
**param name**: display=1&type=myCompany&id=1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil Haack  made a route debugger that does do kind of the same:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Somewhere in the article there is a link to the source code, so you can just take the parts you need.